# Does GLSL support floats in uniform variables?

Tags: opengl, glsl

```
#version 330 core
uniform vec3 ucolor;
uniform float uval;
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
out vec3 out_color;

void main(){
  gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1);
  out_color = ucolor;
}
```

I get:

```
error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $undefined at token "<undefined>"
```

The problem is `uniform float uval;` if I change it to `uniform int uval;`for example it compiles without any problems. `float` seems to be the only type that triggers the compile error

Does OpenGL 3.3 support floats in uniform variables?

According to https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)

> Uniforms can be of any type, or any aggregation of types.

Edit:

The problem seems to go away when I use `uval`. So I assume this could be a driver bug?

Comment: Uniforms are definitely supposed to be able to be floats. However, this doesn't seem like an error indicating that is the issue to begin with; it looks like a parser error (or possibly very bad compiler output). Try printing the shader source to the console - I had a similar weird issue the other day due to unicode byte order marks, and that could be related.

Comment: Looks much more likely to me that the missing `#` in your version directive is to blame. Of course GLSL supports `floats`, that's what GPUs are built for. It's unnormalized integer types that have iffy support.

Comment: In your edit you say the error goes away when you use the value. I am suspecting that this may have something to do with your shader loading code.... OpenGL removes unused uniforms as an optimizaiton at runtime, so maybe you are assuming the uniform exists?

Comment: "unexpected $undefined at token "<undefined>"" ... the quality of GLSL parsers always amazes me ...

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I just failed to copy the whole console output, there really is an `#` before version. I am just going to assume that it is the nvidia driver.

Comment: @MaikKlein: Alright then. I have encountered **C0000** on NV compilers before, it's generally raised because a non-printable character is encountered. More often than not, it would be a stray null terminator (assuming you tell GLSL you are using a C-style string) or simply the wrong string length passed to `glShaderSource (...)`. Check those things first, and if all else fails, read the source code of your shader _back_ from GL to make sure something funky didn't happen.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion of looking for BOMs?

Comment: Check if there are invisible characters in there! Try playing around with the encoding stuff in your text editor. It could definitely throw OpenGL off.